# Bootstrap Tooltips Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I can't get my bootstrap tooltips to work, I've tried literally everything, multiple jQuery versions, multiple bootstrap versions, multiple code snippets (seen a lot of similar problems here on stackoverflow), javascript on the head and after the body, nothing seems to work ...

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
            });
        ​</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Example">Tooltip</button>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use jQuery before it has loaded.

If you look in the console, you will see the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `$` is not defined

To resolve this, move your `script` tag *after* the jQuery library and the Bootstrap JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
  });
​</script>
```

Comment: I tried that, I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on </script> in the console.

Comment: @JoséPereira It works [here](https://jsbin.com/rapipopoqa/edit?html,output) with the exact same HTML/JS: https://jsbin.com/rapipopoqa/edit?html,output

Comment: Oh ok, after the body, it's working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: in bootstrap 5 is still this problem it is async it seems

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Example">Tooltip</button>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
            $(function(){
                $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
            });
        ​</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 problems over here:

1) Initialize jquery first 
2) You have an illegal (invisible) character inserted after your tooltip initialization. It sucks I know, but you need to remove that char.

Following code should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Example">Tooltip</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```